# Как засечь таймер и после его истечения сделать автоматическое действие? Питон

Tags: python, время, таймер

Хочу написать код который измеряет скорость печати на клавиатуре, для этого у меня есть текст который придётся пользователю печатать как можно быстрее, надо засечь таймер в 10 секунд и после их истечения надо чтобы нажался автоматически enter. Так пользователь введёт весь текст который он успел напечатать в input

Comment: Хотите написать - пишите.

Comment: не понятно, зачем вам `input` ?  Покажите что вы уже написали.

Comment: @S.Nick
text = #Здесь текст который будет вводить пользователь на скорость
print(text)
input1 = input("Enter text here:\n")#Здесь пользователь вводит текст который был написан выше
integers = len(input1)
print(f'Your speed of typing is {integers} in 10 seconds')
Это то что уже есть, надо чтобы во время начала input начался таймер в 10 секунд а по его окончанию автоматически нажался enter чтобы пользователь ввёл то что он успел ввести за 10 секунд.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить вариант с "костылем".

Функция `input()` требует обязательного нажатия `enter` для финализации ввода. Можно через `threading.Timer` создать поток, который через 10 секунд будет просить нажать `enter`. При этом считать будем скорость не за 10 секунд, а по факту за промежуток времени определяемый с помощью `time.time()`.

```
import threading
import time

waiting = 10  # секунды
t1 = threading.Timer(waiting, print, args=['Время вышло, нажмите Enter'])
begin = time.time()
t1.start()
text = input('Введите текст:\n')
t1.cancel()
time_count = time.time() - begin
print(f'Скорость ввода {len(text)/time_count} символов в секунду')
```

Comment: Идея хорошая но проблема в том что пользователь в нужное время может не нажать enter и промежуток времени будет больше 10 секунд

Comment: Да, но функция `input()` как я писал выше предполагает завершение только при вводе `enter`. Я думаю, что здесь проще будет с пользовательским интерфейсом сделать что-то. Хотя может коллеги подскажут другой вариант, но я не уверен.